# Effective "almost enumeration" of monotone boolean functions

Tags: co.combinatorics, computational-complexity, computer-science, boolean-algebras

Denote by $\mathcal{M}(n)$ the set of all monotone functions $\{0,1\}^n \to \{0,1\}$.

Can $\mathcal{M}(n)$ be represented as $\mathcal{M}(n) = \{ f(t) | t\in \{0,1\}^k \}$ such that:

1) $k = \log |\mathcal{M}(n)| + O(n)$

2) $f \in DTIME(2^{O(n)})$
?

(I mean that $f(i)$ is a truth table of a boolean function)